# JSON parseData sometimes will gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

When i get JSON from server to IOS, sometimes the parseData will be NULL. Even i try to use wait few seconds and get Data from Server again, it still NULL even i keep looping to check.

The weird part is when i use NSLOG this part on JSONFetcher.m

```
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:Oridata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
parseData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
```

the "Oridata" had data inside, but sometimes "parseData" data will be NULL. And it only happen when the "Oridata" is return group of json data.

I fail to check back where the JSONFecther file source, but those file is come from "Copyright (C) 2009 Stig Brautaset". Is that any one know how the problem come out? thanks a lot.

Comment: How about using that error parameter to see what status is returned. And logging the `responseData`.

Comment: can tell me how to use error parameter? can give me some example? thanks!

Comment: error is this >> Error Domain=org.brautaset.SBJsonParser.ErrorDomain Code=0 "Unexpected end of input" UserInfo=0xa16cda0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of input}

Answer (score 0):

The error `Unexpected end of input` means that `Oridata` is incomplete - either the server returned invalid data or you didn't download all of the data before trying to process it.

Log `responseData` and verify the contents. Then check what you receive and how (using Charles and checking your data collection from the download connection).

Comment: i had try to check it, found out "parseData" look like process too long and the system call the value before it finish. just some time i log the "parseData", it just half complete. is that got any way to prevent or solve this part?

Comment: Parsedata or oridata? How do you get oridata?

Comment: Oridata always had data, just problem always appear on parseData.

Comment: Always has data, or always has *correct and complete* data?

Comment: Oridata always had data and correct and complete. parseData sometime will not complete, just like half of data.

Comment: Error Domain=org.brautaset.SBJsonParser.ErrorDomain Code=0 "Unexpected end of input" UserInfo=0xa16cda0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of input}

Comment: So oridata is incomplete in some way.